# MATLAB: extract most significant bits

Tags: matlab, bit

I am learning MATLAB and am facing problem about extracting most significant bits from a given double. I saw getmsb function. But, is there a function that can give me say 5 most significant bits?

Anil.

Comment: Do you want the 5 MSBs as if it were an integer? Or do you want the 5 MSBs in it's floating point representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's late, so I'm sure there's a better solution. Anyway, this seems to do it:

```
A = rand(1, 1) * 10000
nBits = 5
curBits = ceil(log2(A))
toShift = curBits - nBits
wantedMSB = fix(A / 2^toShift) % This is still a double, feel free to cast.
dec2bin(wantedMSB)             % Result in bitstring form.
```

Or, as one liner:

```
A = rand(1, 1) * 10000
nBits = 5
wantedMSB = fix(A / 2^(ceil(log2(A)) - nBits))
```

*[Edit]* Btw, the `getmsb` function is part of the Fixed-Point Toolbox, which might not be available on every MATLAB installation.